# ServerSide Jquery Datatables TypeError: c is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I try to use jQuery DataTables but I get the error

```
TypeError: c is undefined jquery.dataTables.min.js:36:417
jQuery 8
    ub
    kb
    i
    success
    fire
    fireWith
    done
    callback
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code as I can see the JSON correctly retrieve and is in the correct format too but I don't know what is wrong with it that I get the above error

```
$('#accountsTable').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "pageLength" : 100,
    "ajax" : {
        "url" : "/accountMaster",
    "data": function (data) { 

    }},
"columns": [{
"data": "cid"
}, {
"data": "account"
}, {
     "data": "ifsc"
 }, {
  "data": "purpose"
 }, {
 "data": "requestedby"
 }, {
 "data": "requesteddate"
 }, {
 "data": "action"
 }
 ]
 });
```

Comment: Hi, Please check if the number of <td> matches with the number of columns

Comment: @ameya: Tested,it matched

Comment: Try using datatables.js (not datatables.min.js) to get a (potentially!) more useful error.

Comment: @freedomn-m: can you please provide me link

Comment: What's your current link?  Remove `.min`